# how to use expression in ggplot aestethic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot below. Now I would like the `aes( y =` in my plot to be dynamic, but as of now ggplot seems to take the specified value literally.

How can I make so that it takes my object instead (code below)?

```
qplot.single  <- function(x) {

  SMApointer  <- colnames(x)[grep("SMA", names(x))]
  print(SMApointer)
  gplot  <- ggplot(data = fortify(x), aes(x = published, y = SMApointer )) + geom_line()
  print(gplot)

}
```

Output

```
> qplot(x.ind)
[1] "SMA100"
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SMApointer' not found
```

Comment: `aes_string` probably. `published` will need to be quoted too then, Id guess.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. Please post an answer and I will mark it.